# JSON Adding List<class> to class xxx

Tags: c#, json, list, arraylist

I'm trying to add data to a list then later add it to another list `{

```
{
    "name": "0001",
    "id": "donut",
    "total": {
        "price": [{
                "date": "1001",
                "type": "Regular"
            },
            {
                "id": "1002",
                "type": "Chocolate"
            },
            {
                "id": "1003",
                "type": "Blueberry"
            },
            {
                "id": "1004",
                "type": "Devil's Food"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is what the output Json should look like. Here are some of my codes:

```
public class TotalPrice
{
  public string date { get; set; }
  public string price { get; set; }
}

public class TotalPrices
{
  public List<TotalPrice> Price { get; set; }
}

public class AgencyCompare
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string id { get; set; }
  public TotalPrices total { get; set; }
}

for (int j = 0; j < dtFIT.Rows.Count; j++)
{
  var xTrans = new AgencyCompare();
  var xxx = new List<TotalPrice>();
  Debug.WriteLine("Start xTrans.ID");
  xTrans.id = id[j];
  Debug.WriteLine("End xTrans.ID");
  Debug.WriteLine("Start xTrans.name");
  xTrans.name = name[j];
  Debug.WriteLine("End xTrans.name");
  if (rowCount[j] > 0)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("ROWCOUNT > 0");
    for (int z = 0; z < rowCount[j]; z++)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("Start xTrans2");
      var xTrans2 = new TotalPrice();
      Debug.WriteLine("Start xTrans2.date");
      xTrans2.date = AtDay[j, z];
      Debug.WriteLine("End xTrans2.date");
      Debug.WriteLine("Start xTrans2.price");
      xTrans2.price = TotalPrice[j, z];
      Debug.WriteLine("End xTrans2.price");
      xxx.Add(xTrans2);
      Debug.WriteLine("xTrans.total.Price.Add(xTrans2)");
    }
    xTrans.total.Price.AddRange(xxx);
  }
  else
  {
    //
  }
  //xTrans.date = AtDay[j];
  //xTrans.total = TotalPrice[j];
  Debug.WriteLine("xAryTransCheckIn.Add(xTrans)");
  xAryTransCheckIn.Add(xTrans);
}
return xAryTransCheckIn;
```

Errors when i debug:

> Start xTrans2
>
> Start xTrans2.date
>
> End xTrans2.date
>
> Start xTrans2.price
>
> End xTrans2.price
>
> xTrans.total.Price.Add(xTrans2)
>
> Start xTrans2
>
> Start xTrans2.date
>
> End xTrans2.date
>
> Start xTrans2.price
>
> End xTrans2.price
>
> xTrans.total.Price.Add(xTrans2)
>
> Start xTrans2
>
> Start xTrans2.date
>
> End xTrans2.date
>
> Start xTrans2.price
>
> End xTrans2.price
>
> xTrans.total.Price.Add(xTrans2)
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Webrestful.dll`

The exception is thrown when i called xTrans.total.Price.AddRange(xxx);, i'm not sure whether i set up the correct class format, or i make a mistake when i try to add the list.

Comment: When you debug through it is `total` null? Or is it `Price`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `xTrans.total =new TotalPrices()` and `xTrans.total.Price = new List<TotalPrice>()`